# How to set lock on desktop wallpaper change?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

I want to know that how to disable or lock the permission of changing desktop wallpaper for standard and limited users from admin side.

Is it possible I want to know, if yes then please anyone tell me, how to perform that? I need it because other user change desktop wallpaper that are some vulgar and abused.

Any suggestion please how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `String` key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` named `Wallpaper` containing the path to your wallpaper. That would disable changing wallpaper from Personalization applet and right clicking image file on Explorer.

However, determined user could google this question and modify the key themselves. So the next step would be disabling Registry Editor, which could be defeated by 3rd party apps, which necessitate limiting Windows to only run pre-approved apps, which require a trip to Group Policy editor, which could be still disabled by VB scripts, so you would need to disable VBS execution engine etc...

Or you could just install apps like [Reboot Restore](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=18), [Returnil System Safe](http://www.returnilvirtualsystem.com/returnil-system-safe) or [Toolwiz Time Freeze](http://www.toolwiz.com/products/toolwiz-time-freeze/) so everytime the PC is rebooted, everything return to the clean state

Comment: Thank You sir. I have also get  it using `registryeditor` as well as using `gpedit.msc(group policy)`

Answer (score 2):

I would use Local Group Policy.

Goto `Start -> type gpedit.msc`

Navigate to `User configuration` -> `Administrative Template` -> `Control Panel` -> `Personalization`

Here you have the `Prevent changing desktop background` parameter. Set it to `Enabled`

Comment: +1 Alternatively, go to  User Config -> Admin Template -> Desktop -> Desktop, right click Desktop Wallpaper, Edit, Enable it, and specify your wallpaper - this gives all users on a computer the same wallpaper without the ability to change it